# Could we use session to create a global variable for all client?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I saw this example in php manual page
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php
The example will create a global session for all client. Can I use this example to create some global application for all client, instead of save it to DB or local file. 
What're the pros and cons of this method?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work, but I wouldn't recommend it... to much scope for potential confusion by othe rdevelopers working with the code, potential issues if you update session variables within the wrong scope, and the use of the term "session" for something that is not session-related can lead to a whole world of confusion

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible by sharing the session id between two clients but sessions are only used to store temporary data of a user. So once a session is destroyed there is no way to retrieve that data.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, or advised. A session is bound to one client, and clients do not share a session.

Comment: Actually this is possible if you override default session handling functions. It's just wrong.

Comment: sorry, did you try that example? I try it on two different browsers, and the global session work

Comment: It might work, but I wouldn't recommend it... to much scope for potential confusion by othe rdevelopers working with the code, potential issues if you update session variables within the wrong scope, and the use of the term "session" for something that is not session-related can lead to a whole world of confusion.

Comment: @Mark Baker: thanks for comment. Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it :) because I cannot accept a comment as an answer